# How to prevent page been dragged when panel is open in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panel, swipe

When I open the panel on swiperight and then closed on swipeleft and if I press too much and then swipe left the panel doesn't close, instead it's moving me to the main content with panel still opened and the half of the main content is blank how can I fix this here is my HTML code. This only happens if I hold down for 1 second and then move with the finger on my phone.

This is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/panel.js"></script>
        <title>Photosi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id='main-page'>
            <div data-role='panel' id='main-panel' data-display='reveal'>
            <ul data-role='listview'>
                <li><a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='camera' data-iconpos='left'>Albums</a></li>
                <li><a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='user' data-iconpos='left'>Social</a></li>
                <li><a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='star' data-iconpos='left'>Effects</a></li>
                <li><a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='arrow-u' data-iconpos='left'>Upload</a></li>
                <li><a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='gear' data-iconpos='left'>Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='info' data-iconpos='left'>Help</a></li>
                <li><a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='left'>Exit</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header">
                <a href='#main-panel' class='ui-btn ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all'></a>
                <h1>Albums</h1>
            </div>

            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>Page content goes here.</p>
                <a href='#mypanel' class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"></a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my panel js code:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#main-page", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swiperight", "#main-page", function( e ) {
        if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ){
            $('#main-panel').panel('open');

        }

    });

    $( document ).on( "swipeleft", "#main-page", function( e ) {
        if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) == "open" ){
            $('#main-panel').panel('close');

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the panel [dismissible](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#option-dismissible). This means it will close if someone clicks off of it.